# Converting hours between SPSS and R

Tags: r, lubridate

I constructed hourly data in SPSS. With Starttime 7:00 and EndTime 7:59. When I read these in R,I get such numbers:  57600  & 61140. How do I get R to recognize these values as hours? Thanks for your help**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

I guess those numbers that you get in `R` are the corresponding hours in seconds, e.g. 02:51:03 = 2*60*60 + 51*60 + 3 = 10263 seconds. The thing that doesn't fit my guess is that 7:00 is not 57600 seconds but either is 25200 seconds (am)  or 68400 seconds (pm). 57600 seconds corresponds to 16:00 (4:00 pm).

If those values are actually seconds, then you can turn them into time with something like the following function `toHour`.

```
    toHour <- function(x, seconds = F)  # x is a value of seconds
    {
     hours <- x %/% 3600
     secs. <- x %% 3600
     mins <- secs. %/% 60
     secs <- secs. %% 60

     ## add a 0 to single-digit hours / minutes / seconds to make it look nicer  
     mytime <- c(hours, mins, secs)
     for(i in 1:length(mytime))  
      {
       if(length(unlist(strsplit(as.character(mytime[i]), split = ""))) == 1)
        {
         mytime[i] <- paste(0, mytime[i], sep = "", collapse = "")
        }
      }
     ##

    if(seconds == T)
      {
       return(paste(mytime[1], mytime[2], mytime[3], sep = ":", collapse = ""))
      }
     if(seconds == F)
      {
       return(paste(mytime[1], mytime[2], sep = ":", collapse = ""))
      }
    }

    toHour(10263, seconds = T) # check function
    #[1] "02:51:03" #checked
    my_seconds <- seq(57600,61140, 60) # I guess you have no seconds in your time and, so, "my_seconds" is the values you get in R
    sapply(my_seconds, toHour) # turn all values (seconds) to hours:minutes
    #[1] "16:00" "16:01" "16:02" "16:03" "16:04" ...
    sapply(my_seconds, toHour, seconds = T) # turn all values (seconds) to hours:minutes:seconds
    #[1] "16:00:00" "16:01:00" "16:02:00" "16:03:00" ...
```

I'm sorry if I misunderstood the question or my post is irrelevant, but I couldn't ask for details in a comment due to my low reputation.

EDIT: `toHour` returns character values. The next step is:

```
    library(chron)
    chron(times. = sapply(my_seconds, toHour, seconds = T))
    #[1] 16:00:00 16:01:00 16:02:00 16:03:00 16:04:00 ...
```